# packaged_task operator() get exception

Tags: c++, c++11, std, packaged-task

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int simple_task(int i) { return i*3; }

int main() {
    std::packaged_task<int(int)> task(simple_task);

    auto fut = task.get_future();

    try {
        task(10); // why ???? got exception ??
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Triple 10 is " << fut.get() << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
exception caught: Unknown error -1
```

Am I using it in a wrong way ? I just want to test operator() function.
I know how to use it with std::thread.

Ubuntu 15.04

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.2-    10ubuntu13' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13
```

Comment: Please tell what kind of exception you're getting. That would help.

Comment: It runs fine for me on windows, going to try on linux now.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem (http://ideone.com/rYS2BB) when I try with something else. I'm guessing it's a gcc bug.

Comment: gcc 4.9.2 on windows (MinGW) is fine so I'm guessing this is linux-specific.

Comment: I think you need a thread option on linux, such as `-pthread`. I don't quite understand why, but it makes the exception disappear.

Comment: -lpthread didn't help. Still the same.